How to stop ufw-firewall preventing me to ssh into another server?
I have a weird issue on Ubuntu 22.4.4 LTS.
Using the ufw firewall, I allowed SSH/Port 22, HTTP and HTTPS. I can successfully login via SSH into my server. However, when I am logged in on the server, and want to SSH from their to another server, it gets somehow blocked and is just hanging.
But when I want to SSH from the second server to the first one, this works using SSH agent and SSH forwarding.
Both servers use default Port 22.
When I disable the firewall on Server 1 using sudo ufw disable, I can SSH from Server 1 to Server 2. When enabling the firewall again, it just hangs.
So, to render it little simpler:

Working OK: MacBook -> SSH -> Server 1
Not working: Server 1 -> SSH -> Server 2
Working OK: Server2 -> SSH -> Server 1

My firewall configuration on server 1 is the following:
> sudo ufw status numbered

Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 9418/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 3] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 443                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 5] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 7] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 8] 123                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 9] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[10] 9418/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[11] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[12] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[13] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[14] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[15] 53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[16] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[17] 123 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[18] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Status Verbose:
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9418/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
123                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9418/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
123 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
443                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)

Is there another port I need to open that will be used when SSH out from Server 1 to another server? Or allowing UDP or something like that?

Provide the firewall configuration of the other server

It's not a weird issue; you just literally do not have a rule that would allow port 22 outbound – your list only has an ALLOW IN rule but not an ALLOW OUT one, and since it's set to deny by default, the outbound connection to remote port 22 is blocked.

What is the command "sudo ufw allow ssh" doing that it is not allowing OUT, only IN?

Not sure what you mean, but I think allowing IN is the default operation in ufw, as most users don't restrict outbound connections.
